# creating abstract components that can manage external data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Currently I use Vuetify for base components and would like to create reusable extensions. For example a list containing checkboxes, a datatable column with some functionality etc.

For this question I will take the **list containing checkboxes** example. I created the following component called **CheckboxGroup.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-checkbox
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      v-model="item.state"
      :label="item.title"
    ></v-checkbox>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    items: Array,
    required: true
  }
};
</script>
```

This component takes an array of objects as a property and creates a checkbox for each entry.

Important parts are `v-model="item.state"` and `:label="item.title"`. Most of the time the `state` attribute will have a different name, same for the `title` attribute.

For testing purposes I created a view file called **Home.vue** holding an array of documents.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <CheckboxGroup :items="documents"/>
    <v-btn @click="saveSettings">Save</v-btn>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import CheckboxGroup from "../components/CheckboxGroup";

export default {
  components: {
    CheckboxGroup
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      documents: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Doc 1",
          deleted: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Doc 2",
          deleted: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Doc 3",
          deleted: true
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveSettings: function() {
      console.log(this.documents);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This time `title` is called `name` and `state` is called `deleted`. Obviously `CheckboxGroup` is not able to manage the documents because the attribute names are wrong.

How would you solve this problem? Would you create a computed property and rename these attributes? Would be a bad idea I think...

And by the way, is using `v-model` a good idea? A different solution would be to listen to the changed event of a checkbox and emit an event with the item index. Then you would have to listen for the change in the parent component.

I don't think there is a way to create something like

```
<CheckboxGroup :items="documents" titleAttribute="name" stateAttribute="deleted"/>
```

because it would be bad design anyway. I hope that this is a very trivial problem and every Vue developer has been confronted with it, since the primary goal should always be to develop abstract components that can be reused multiple times.

Please keep in mind that this checkbox problem is just an example. A solution for this problem would also solve same or similar problems :)

Comment: `> because it would be bad design anyway.` Why so? Vuetify uses similar approach for `v-select`, i.e.`item-value` and  `item-text`.

Comment: ^^^ Couldn't agree more - I think OP has a better understanding of the "paradigm" or "design" than OP thinks - OP's example is already flexible and reusable..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood what you wanted, it`s not so trivial. Using props is a good idea. You dont need to manage the documents attribute names, just set the attribute name to your component.

**Note**

*Renaming the attributes or using proxies is more resource-intensive like this solution, because you need to run loop to rename the attribute names or apply aliases to data array objects.*

**Example**

**CheckboxGroup.vue**

```
  <template>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-checkbox 
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
          v-model="item[itemModel]" 
          :label="item[itemValue]"
        ></v-checkbox>
        <hr>
        {{items}}
      </v-container>
    </template>
    <script>

    export default {
      name: "CheckboxGroup",
       props: {

        items: {
          type: Array,
          required:true
        },

        itemValue:{
          type:String,
          default: 'title',

           // validate props if you need
          //validator: function (value) {
          //  return ['title', 'name'].indexOf(value) !== -1
          // }
          // or make required
        },

        itemModel:{
          type:String,
          default: 'state',

           // validate props if you need
           //validator: function (value) {
            // validate props if you need
            // return ['state', 'deleted'].indexOf(value) !== -1
           // }
         // or make required
        }

      }
    };
    </script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>

  <div id="app">
    <checkbox-group :items="documents"
      item-value="name"
      item-model="deleted"
    >

    </checkbox-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CheckboxGroup from "./CheckboxGroup.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    // HelloWorld,
    CheckboxGroup
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      documents: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Doc 1",
          deleted: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Doc 2",
          deleted: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Doc 3",
          deleted: true
        }
      ]
    }
}
};
</script>
```

Based on your example I`v tried to show how to create component to managing object attributes in child component. If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: I tried to create a codesandbox based on your code https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-with-vuetify-eagles-s9oxy I think this is a working approach. But I was hoping to find a documentation for this because I think there should be a general / best practise guide out there ... ?

Comment: if you don't mind I would like to wait some days maybe someone got another approach

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't link any documentation to this topic :(  Maybe later .... I'm showed to you the easiest way to do this in Vue, but if you check how vuetify's code on github  the utils file https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/util/helpers.ts on line 225 contains function called `getPropertyFromItem ` and it is called in https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.js  v-select component (not only) in function `getValue (item) `(line 528). This is working the same way I'm showed to you (line 80 `itemValue`).

Comment: But creating components like this, need deep understanding of TypeScript or Javascript.

Comment: This is the simplest solution.

Comment: The only thing I would change is drop the props validators, the component will fail on first run if incorrectly wired up.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! I left a comment but I not commented the validator ...

Comment: Your note about needing to "run loop to find attribute names" is inaccurate. Looping isn't actually needed. You might be referring to `Object.keys(aliasMap).includes(key)`, but that line could be replaced with `key in aliasMap`, or `aliasMap.hasOwnProperty(key)`, or simply `aliasMap[key]` -- none of which require looping.

Comment: Yeah. You are not entirely right. Why? When you create your proxy object with attribute aliases, it also need to apply to your data array, but it is not possible without iteration (looping) `this.documents.map(doc => aliasProps(doc, aliases));` all the items in the data array right? This means you first of all create a proxy object and run an extra loop.  That's working in many situations, but I guess it's not the best solution. Why?  Creating a proxy and iterate more resource-intensive than simply setting the name. Renaming attributes same problem (extra loop). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sabee, yes I would say that `this.documents.map(doc => aliasProps(doc, aliases))` constitutes a loop over documents prior to passing in to the child. I can't see this map being lazy, as it might in (say) an RxJS mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Some good answers here that definitely solve your issue - you are essentially wanting to pass data down to a child (which isn't bad design - you were on the right track!)..

I am kind of shocked that [`slots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) or [`scoped-slots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) haven't been mentioned yet... so I figured I would chime in..

Scoped-slots allow you to take advantage of data you are passing to a child - but within the parent.  The child essentially "reflects" data back to the parent, which allows you to style the child component/slot however you wish, from the parent.

This is different than just passing data via a prop attribute, because you would have to rely on styling within the child - you couldn't change the styles on a 'per-use' basis. The styles you set in the child would be "hard coded"..

In this example I am riding on top of the already provided [`label` slot that Vuetify provides](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#api) - just passing my own custom `scoped-slot` to it.. [***How to find documentation on v-checkbox slots***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tZlg.png)

I made some minor changes to help spice some things up, and to show how you have greater control over styles this way (and you can use any object prop for the label you want `.name`, `.whatever`, `.label`, etc..)

Lastly, it is important to note that `Vuetify` already provides a "grouped checkbox" component - `v-radio-group` - I know it's called "radio-group" but it supports checkboxes...

*Edit:* fixed the `state` "issue"...

[image: Edit Vue with Vuetify - Eagles]

**Scoped Slots With Render Function - Original Answer Moved To Bottom**

***Thanks to @Estradiaz for collaborating on this with me!***

```js
Vue.component('checkboxgroup', {
  props: {
    items: { type: Array, required: true }
  },
  render (h) {
    return h('v-container', this.items.map((item) => {
      return this.$scopedSlots.checkbox({ item });
    }));
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    documents: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Doc 1 - delete",
        deleted: false,
        icon: "anchor",
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        title: "Doc 1 - state",
        state: false,
        icon: "anchor",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Doc 2 - delete",
        deleted: false,
        icon: "mouse"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Doc 3 - delete",
        deleted: true,
        icon: "watch"
      }
    ]
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/2.1.99/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <CheckboxGroup :items="documents">
       <template #checkbox={item}>          
          <v-checkbox 
            v-model="item[(item.name && 'deleted') || (item.title && 'state') ]" color="red">
            <template #label>              
              <v-icon>mdi-{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
              {{ item.name || item.title }}
              {{ item }}
            </template>
          </v-checkbox>
        </template>
      </CheckboxGroup>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: oh you are so right one can just simply fit assignments as needed

Comment: I disagree, respectfully, while this is a great tutorial on slots it only does half the job. Look at the snippet, Doc1 is checked but it should be Doc3. You need a lot more code to make this work properly, and that code needs to be added to every component that uses `CheckboxGroup`.

Comment: i put it to my anwser with referencing you - because i think this is the vue way doing dynamic json components

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) to map the document property names during access.

**Note**
In my original answer, I used **Proxy** handlers for `get` and `set`, which is sufficient for plain javascript objects, but fails when used with Vue `data` properties because of the observer wrappers that Vue applies.

By also trapping `has` in the **Proxy**, this can be overcome. I left the original answer below for anyone interested in this problem.

Here is a demo of how to use **Proxy** to 'alias' Vue reactive properties to different names

- without affecting the original data structure
- without having to copy the data

```js
console.clear()
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

Vue.component('checkboxgroup', {
  template: '#checkboxGroup',
  props: { items: Array, required: true },
});

const aliasProps = (obj, aliasMap) => {
  const handler = {
    has(target, key) {
      if (key in aliasMap) {
        return true;  // prevent Vue adding aliased props
      }
      return key in target;
    },
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      const propToGet = aliasMap[prop] || prop;
      return Reflect.get(target, propToGet);
    },
    set(target, prop, value, receiver) {
      const propToSet = aliasMap[prop] || prop;
      return Reflect.set(target, propToSet, value)
    }
  };
  return new Proxy(obj, handler);
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    documents: [
      { id: 1, name: "Doc 1", deleted: false },
      { id: 2, name: "Doc 2", deleted: false },
      { id: 3, name: "Doc 3", deleted: true },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    checkBoxItems() {
      const aliases = {
        title: 'name',
        state: 'deleted'
      }
      return this.documents.map(doc => aliasProps(doc, aliases));
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveSettings: function() {
      console.log(this.documents);
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="theapp">
    <v-container>
      <checkboxgroup :items="checkBoxItems"></checkboxgroup>
      <v-btn color="info" 
             @click="saveSettings">Save</v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

<template id="checkboxGroup">
  <v-container style="display: flex">
    <v-checkbox
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
      v-model="item.state" 
      :label="item.title"
    ></v-checkbox>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

---

**Original answer**

You can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) to map the document property names during access.

```js
<template>
  ...
  <CheckboxGroup :items="checkBoxItems"/>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    ...
    computed: {
      checkBoxItems() {
        const handler = {
          get: function(target, prop) {
            return prop === 'title' ? target.name :
              prop === 'state' ? target.deleted :
              target[prop];
          },
          set(obj, prop, value) {
            const propToSet = 
              prop === 'title' ? 'name' :
              prop === 'state' ? 'deleted' :
              prop;
            obj[propToSet] = value;
          }
        };
        return documents.map(doc => new Proxy(doc, handler))
      },
    },
    ...
  }
</script>
```

**Demo**

```js
const documents = [
  { id: 1, name: "Doc 1", deleted: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Doc 2", deleted: false },
  { id: 3, name: "Doc 3", deleted: true },
]

const handler = {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    return prop === 'title' ? target.name :
      prop === 'state' ? target.deleted :
      target[prop];
  },
  set(obj, prop, value) {
    const propToSet = 
      prop === 'title' ? 'name' :
      prop === 'state' ? 'deleted' :
      prop;
     obj[propToSet] = value;
  }
};
const checkItems = documents.map(doc => new Proxy(doc, handler))

console.log('Accessing new property names via checkItems')
checkItems.forEach(ci => console.log(ci.id, ci.title, ci.state))

console.log('After update, values of documents')
checkItems.forEach(ci => ci.state = !ci.state )
documents.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.id, doc.name, doc.deleted))
```

Answer (score 1):

### My attempt of a json to component parser

***usefull names are welcome***

---

so basically you can target element tagnames as slot `#[slotname]` or put slot names and target entries to overwrite the default component.

omiting `tag` property in the component will append children to the parent `vnode`

---

Consider:

```
      [
        {
            ElementTag: 'Liste',
            id: 1,
            tag: 'p',
            items: [
                {
                    ElementTag: 'input',
                    id: 11,
                    type: 'checkbox',
                    title: "Sub Doc 1 - state",
                    state: true,
                    slotName: "slotvariant"
                },
                {
                    ElementTag: 'input',
                    id: 12,
                    type: 'date',
                    title: "Sub Doc 2 - Date",
                    date: "",
                }        
            ]
        },
        {
            ElementTag: 'input',
            id: 2,
            type: 'checkbox',
            title: "Doc 2 - deleted",
            deleted: true,
            slotName: 'deleted'
        }
    ]
```

---

Example :

```js
Vue.component('Liste', {
props:["tag", "items"],
render(h){
        console.log(this.items)
        let tag = this.tag || (this.$parent.$vnode && this.$parent.$vnode.tag)
        if(tag === undefined) throw Error(`tag property ${tag} is invalid. Scope within valid vnode tag or pass valid component/ html tag as property`)
        return h(tag, this.items.map(item => {
            const {ElementTag, slotName, ...attrs} = item;
            return (
              this.$scopedSlots[slotName || ElementTag]
            && this.$scopedSlots[slotName || ElementTag]({item})
            )
            || h(ElementTag, {
                attrs: attrs,
                scopedSlots: this.$scopedSlots
                
            })
        }))
    }
})

new Vue({
  data(){
    
    return {
        items:  [
            {
                ElementTag: 'Liste',
                id: 1,
                tag: 'p',
                items: [
                    {
                        ElementTag: 'input',
                        id: 11,
                        type: 'checkbox',
                        text: "Sub Doc 1 - state",
                        state: true,
                        slotName: "slotvariant"
                    },
                    {
                        ElementTag: 'input',
                        id: 12,
                        type: 'date',
                        title: "Sub Doc 2 - Date",
                        date: "",
                    }        
                ]
            },
            {
                ElementTag: 'input',
                id: 2,
                type: 'checkbox',
                title: "Doc 2 - deleted",
                deleted: true,
                slotName: 'deleted'
            }
        ]}
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <Liste tag="p" :items="items">
  <template #input="{item}">
      <label :for="item.id">
        {{ item.title }}
      </label>
      <input :type="item.type" :id="item.id" v-model="item.date"/>
    </template>
    <template #slotvariant="{item}">
      slotvariant - {{item.text}}<br>
    </template>
    <template #deleted="{item}">
      <label :for="item.id">
        {{ item.title }}
      </label>
      <input :type="item.type" :id="item.id" v-model="item.deleted"/>
    </template>
  </Liste>
</div>
```

---

> Typescript:

```
import {Vue, Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator'
export type AbstractElement = {
    [key: string]: any // passed as $attrs |  useable for assigned $props
    ElementTag: string
    slotName?: string
}
@Component<List>({

    render(h){

        let tag = this.tag 
        || (this.$parent.$vnode && this.$parent.$vnode.tag) 
        || (this.$parent.$el && this.$parent.$el.tagName)
        if(tag === undefined) throw Error(`tag prperty: ${tag} is invalid. Scope within valid vnode tag or pass valid component/ html tag as property`)
        return h(tag, this.items.map(item => {
            const {ElementTag, slotName, ...attrs} = item;
            console.log("slotName", slotName)
            return (this.$scopedSlots[slotName || ElementTag]
            && this.$scopedSlots[slotName || ElementTag]({item}))
            || h(ElementTag, {
                attrs: attrs,
                slot: slotName || ElementTag,
                scopedSlots: this.$scopedSlots
            })
        }))
    }
})
export default class List extends Vue{
    @Prop(String) readonly tag?: string
    @Prop(Array) readonly items!: Array<AbstractElement>
}
```

[will raise this here](https://github.com/Estradiaz/vue-json-to-component)